# End of stream encountered before parsing was completed but stream position = 0

Tags: c#, parsing, serialization, stream, formatter

I am trying to serialize an object but I keep getting the following error:

> End of stream encountered before parsing was completed

I am setting the stream position to 0 before reading, I made sure I am using the same formatter (Binary Formatter) when reading and writing , and I also make sure I am flushing the stream. What else can I do. Below, you can find my code.

```
Stream stream = File.Open("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
bFormatter.Serialize(stream, searchPage);
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
```

Comment: In the example you provided you haven't set the position to 0.

Comment: So, is `MyFile.bin` size 0? What about your reading code? Where's that?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: You don't show any code that reads from the stream. You just show how you write to it and *close* it.